# Cocos2d iphone: changing CCSprite.position works on simulator but not on device

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator, ccsprite

I've got a problem with some cocos2d code,
it runs fine on the simulator (means in that case that sprites are moving when I touch and scroll) but it doesn't work on my ipod
The ccTouchesMoved is called on both, but sprite move only in the simulator

```
CCSprite *gradA = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grad.png"];
gradA.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
gradA.position = ccp(0, 0);

[...]

-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    //NSLog(@"ccTouchesMoved called");

    UITouch *touch   = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    int d = (_prevTouch.y - location.y);
    // This code should make the sprite moving
    // And it does on the simulator but not on my ipod
    gradA.position = ccp(PARALAX_X, gradA.position.y - d);

    _prevTouch = location;
}

-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch   = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    _firstTouch = location;
}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    UITouch *touch   = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    _lastTouch = location;
}
```

BTW if I do a "gradA.position = ccp(0, gradA.position.y - d);"
in any other method than ccTouchesMoved it works on device and simulator.

It could be a stupid mistake (and I hope it is) on my side because it's my first project.

Comment: where do you update _prevTouch? Set a breakpoint and check the value of d, it's probably 0.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D _prevTouch is updated in the ccTouchesMoved method, I'm sorry I cut off some code to keep it short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, and if you have problem between a device and the simulator you should check that (as well as filename case)
NSLog is very slow on device, so slow that it prevents the device to render the sprite movement.

I had two NSLogs in my code in the ccTouchesMoved method, 
when I removed them it works like a charm.

Avoid using NSLog on device.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I am moving my sprites at the moment (in ccTouchesMoved):

```
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
    oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
    oldTouchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldTouchLocation];

    CGPoint translation = ccpSub(touchLocation, oldTouchLocation);

    CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(currentFragment.position, translation);
    currentFragment.position = newPos;
```